# General structure of the classes of a manager game

Tags: c++, class

I want to create some text-based soccer manager game , at least give it a try. After long thinking and some tries i am still not sure about the structur of the classes. My first idea was to create something like this:

```
class Player
{
private:
    Team team:
};

class Team
{
    vector<Player> playerlist;
};
```

Do you think it is clever to work with direct assess this way or to use pointer like this instead:

```
class Player
{
private:
    Team* team:
};

class Team 
{
    vector<Player*> playerlist:
};
```

And then i don't know if i should use vector or lists, considering that transfers will change the length and vectors will change the addresses of the players stored into them. So pointers to this vectors could be a problem.

So I'm quite unsure about it, mostly due to my poor experience with C++. What do you think is the best way to set it up?

Comment: The first one looks weird... A `Player` containing a `Team` containing a vector of `Player` containing a `Team` each....

Comment: The Player does not want to own/contain the Team which is what you've done in the first idea. You would just want some kind of reference to it (among many other possibilities) as per your second idea. Usually if your design is somewhat fleshed out (is it?), these things fall into place more easily.

Comment: Your first idea is definitely wrong, because it wouldn't work. There's a circular dependency between player and team (player requires an instance of team, and team requires a list of player instances). Your second idea is certainly an improvement, but you should consider using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) to avoid memory leaks, rather than raw pointers. Also, because this is primarily an opinion based question, I'm going to vote to close it (nothing personal).

Comment: I don't see why you're using classes with private members and all that here.  Just write the code that does what it needs to and save the dressing for a more appropriate occasion.

Comment: @tmyklebu How should i store my data instead ? I read them in from a txt.file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break you classes down into logical groupings. I usually find a good way to start is to write a short paragraph about what your game is about. Split out all the nouns - these are usually classes or properties. Split out all the verbs - these are usually methods.

Does a player contain a team? Or does a team contain a player? If you want the player to know about the team, you could do something like this.

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player() : m_myTeam(NULL) {}
        void SetTeam(Team* team);

    private:
        Team* m_myTeam;
};

class Team
{
    public:
       void AddPlayer(Player* player);

    private:
       std::vector<Player*> m_players;
};
```

Another thing I'd consider here, is that teams *don't create players*. Players should be created by some sort of factory, as a player can come and go from a team as they please, providing their contracts allow it! :D

Comment: Thx but my structure already looks like this ! And i do create the players before, of course ;)

Comment: Ah yeah! It is the same! Haha in that case I think you're doing well.

Comment: I'm confused if your structure already looks like this, then why the original question? The bottom line is: use an indirect way of referring to your Player's team membership (pointer, team ID/number, whatever). And with the vector, probably store smart pointers as already mentioned. Because remember, your objects (Players) will get copied around a lot in a std container. And use nullptr not NULL :)

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that this makes sense because i changed the structure already sometimes and evertime i thought: Wow, yes, this is really clever only to find out that it is'nt;) Thx for the help i will start the project !

Comment: To be honest, I'm sick of the smart pointer rally that gets thrown around here. I think the _worst_ thing to be teaching new programmers is how to not worry about their memory allocations.